# Gatsbyjs page alike logo grey carousel

Tags: javascript, css, carousel

[image: Gastbyjs page logo carousel]

May I know how to do a carousel like this? This is autoplay smoothly non-stop and when hover it pause. It looks very lightweight and minimal.

The link to this is: https://www.gatsbyjs.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply use pure CSS and HTML to do that no JavaScript needed, this example was applied on a marquee spans text but you can use the same method on whatever you want to animate.

I've created a demonstration for you, check it out.

```css
.gatsbyjsSlider {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #eee;
  padding: 5px;
}

.gatsbyjsSlider .items {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 100%;
  animation: gatsbyjsSlider 50s linear infinite;
}

.gatsbyjsSlider .items:hover {
  animation-play-state: paused
}

/* Make it move */
@keyframes gatsbyjsSlider {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
  }

  100% {
    transform: translate(-100%, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Gatsbyjs Slider</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="gatsbyjsSlider">
        <div class="items">
            <!-- Put your image that contain all logos-->
            <img src="https://images.ctfassets.net/vkdbses00qqt/6gYYhIZTJq0VHl3tXT8oPC/18d49aaa1fd3fed25b6b6593350897b7/homepage-used-by-logos__2_.png?w=1731&h=24&q=80&fit=fill" alt="Image">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Wow, your answer is awesome. Thanks!

Comment: My pleasure)) , you can also add images separately and apply `display: flex;` on items.